# Alternates for 'System.import '

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, webpack-2, webpack-4

After updating webpack, System.import start showing a deprecation error.

```
if (typeof System === 'undefined' || typeof System.import === 
 'undefined') {
 global.System = {};
 System.import = module => Promise.resolve(require(module));
```

}

Below is the loadRoute :

```
    function loadRoute(routePromise, reducerPromises = null) {
    return () => {
        routePromise = routePromise
            .then(module => (module.default ? module.default : module))
            .catch(err => console.error('Dynamic page loading failed', err));

        if (reducerPromises === null) {
            return routePromise;
        }

        return injectReducerAndRender(reducerPromises, routePromise);
    };
}
```

Route

```
<Route                       
 path="configuration/school-setup"
 getComponent={loadRoute(                
 System.import('./modules/Configuration/pages/SchoolSetup/SchoolSetup'),
 )}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
import('path/...and/some/more/to/get/over/the/character/limit')
```

Comment: anything more, other than import

Comment: @costaloktopus Why, would `import()` not work? It's the standard now

Comment: I have tried that already, giving me some syntex error.
I'll try one more time. 
Thank You.

Comment: Just remove `System.`, otherwise the code you posted should work. Also, there seems to be a stray `,` at the end of the line...

Comment: Got it, I forgot to remove ',' last time.

Comment: @costaloktopus If it works, could you accept the answer? :)

Comment: if (typeof System === 'undefined' || typeof System.import === 'undefined') 
      global.System = {};
      System.import = module => Promise.resolve(require(module));
     };

not able to convert this. Please Help!

Comment: `if (typeof System == 'undefined' || typeof System.import == 'undefined') global.System = {}; System.import = import`

Comment: Are you using SystemJS? Also, what version of webpack?

Comment: Not using Sustemjs and webpack 4

Comment: And where is `loadRoute` defined?

Comment: I am sharing the loadroute in a while

Comment: loadRoute is use to inject reducers.